# internal string encoding

Tags: encoding, asp-classic

I'm trying to understand how ASP classic handles strings internally. I've googled and debugged, but I still don't know how a string is encoded within the ASP script.

See the illustration below.

**Is input data transformed so that all string variables have the same encoding no matter what source?**

Most ASP-pages are saved on disk as utf-8. They do however #include asp-files that are saved with another encoding. A the top of front-end-pages I set the Response encoding to unicode.

```
response.codepage = 65001   //unicode
reponse.charset = 'utf-8'
```

http://www.designerline.se/db/aspclassicencoding.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all its worth considering that the both UTF-8 and Windows-1252 (and ISO-8859-1 and others) are based on US-ASCII.  The first 128 characters in all of these codepages are identical. Use exactly the same byte value and all occupy just one byte.

In many cases the vast majority of the content is within the US-ASCII range so its hard to tell there is any difference between.  Frequently the whole file is just using US-ASCII characters and hence the files are identical despite choosen encoding (save perhaps the BOM at the start of the file).

**Basic Script Processing**

First the processor combines an ASP file with all its includes and the includes of those includes.  This is done very simply sequentially replacing the include markers with the content of the include file being referenced.  This is done purely at the byte level not attempt is made to convert files of different encodings.

Next the combined version of the file is parsed. tokenized, "compiled" even into a tight interperter friendly file.  Its at this point that chunks of content in the file (the stuff outside of script code blocks) are turned into a special form of `Response.Write`.  Its special in that at the point script execution would reach these special writes the processor simply copies verbatim the bytes as found in the file directly to the output stream, again no attempt is made to convert any encodings.

**Script code and character encoding**

The ASP processor just doesn't cope well with anything that isn't ASCII.  All your code and especially your string literals in your code should only be in ASCII.

What can be a bit confusing once a script is executing all string variables are stored using Unicode encoding.

When code writes content the response using the proper `Response.Write` method this is where the `Response.CodePage` comes into effect.  It will encode the unicode string the script provides to the response code page before adding it to the output stream.

**What is the effect of Response.CharSet**

It adds the CharSet attribute to the `Content-Type` http header.  That is it, it has no other impact.  If set this one character set but send different one because either your Response.CodePage doesn't match it or because the byte content of the files are not in that encoding then you can expect problems.

**Input encoding**

Things get really messy here.  When form data is posted to the server there is no provision in the form url encoding standard to declare the code page used.  Browser can be told what encoding to use and they will default to the charset of the html page contain the form, but there is no mechanism to communicate that choice to the server.

ASP takes the view that the codepage of posted form fields would be the same as the codepage of the response its about to send.  Take a moment to absorb that.... This means that quite counter intuatively the `Response.CodePage` value has an impact on the strings returned by `Request.Form`.  For this reason its important to get the correct codepage set early, doing some form processing and then setting the codepage later just before sending a response can lead to unexpected results.

**The classic "the web page looks fine but the data in the database is corrupt" gotcha**

One common gotcha this behaviour results in is where the developer has set CharSet="UTF-8" but left the codepage at something like "Windows-1252".

What ends up happening is the user enters text which is sent to the server in UTF-8 encoding but the script code reads it as 1252.  This corrupt string gets stored in the database.  A subsequent web page looks at this data, the corrupt string it pulled from the DB.  This string is then sent by response.write using 1252 encoding but the destination page is told its UTF-8.  This has the effect of reversing the corruption and everything looks fine to the user.

However when other components, say a report generator, creates content from the database then the data appears corrupt because it is.

**The Bottom Line**

You are already doing the correct thing, get that CharSet and CodePage set early and consistently.  Where other files may not be saved as UTF-8 you will have problems if there is non-ascii content in them but otherwise you would be fine.

Many include asps are purely code with no content and since that code ought to be purely in ascii its encoding doesn't really matter.

Comment: Big thanks for the detailed answer. I had a few laughs as well! :) Its interesting that ASP uses Unicode to store strings, but does not care what encoding the source have. That means that the programmer must always keep that in mind when handling strings. I guess that most people consider that perfectly ok, but since ASP does not offer any encoding detection or encoding conversions (say 1252 to unicode), it will be near impossible to actually do anything about it.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much again for the answer! It cleared up some of my uncertainties about ASP classic.