# Ajax loading page CodePage and CharSet Issue

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp-classic

I'm working on a project in Japanese language. Part of the page is loading via ajax. Everything in the page is nice and clean but the part that load via ajax cannot render the CodePage and CharSet. Im working with ASP Classic and I added the header to the source page like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.AddHeader "lang", "ja"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

When I add this header all the characters that load from server are fine but the local text area scrambled (A). When I remove the header all the local characters are fine and the server sides are scrambled(B)

[image]

Any idea how can I solv this issue? Is there any way I can do this trough ajax?
I already tried `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",` but it seems not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you set the same encoding and charset on both pages? Is the problem consistent across all browsers?

I also think its recommended to set the charset inside the `<HEAD>` tag as well

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: I have this error in all browser and I have head tag in all pages.

Comment: @Jay. The part that has the wrong encoding, is it coming from a database or is it hardcoded with the asp-code?

Comment: @Jay. See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937509/internal-string-encoding It might help you

Comment: Thanks for reference. It just helped me and the reason was ASP header basically works on what is loading server side and I should have take care of local text as well with regular html meta tags. Thanks again.