# Wrong charset in ASP classic loaded via AJAX

Tags: ajax, encoding, asp-classic, character-encoding, windows-1252

I have issue with dynamic loading of part of content on ASP classic page. I use AJAX to load  on page dynamically, depending on dropdown selected option. Generated  contains some Labels for containing dropdowns and option text inside of dropdowns. Labels are constants encoded in UTF-8 and contain some western European accented characters, and option texts are loaded from database, contain accented characters too but are coded in ANSI.  tags are set to utf-8 but it affects only first load of page, cos its all put together on page. After selecting other options, AJAX fills  with elements and it loads labels well but options text is messed up, so i guess AJAX doesnt load up encoding with text second and etc. times. Work-around was to change label text in constants and set 
<% Response.Charset = "windows-1252" %> on page that is beeing loaded first time.
Now, i want to find better way for this, prefferably in AJAX response to set it all to UTF-8 or windows-1225, or to set each element on page to have different coding with ajax. I even tried Replace function from ASP classic, it works , but again it needs for each new accented letter other replace. Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to solve encoding issues is to switch to utf-8. Not only does it take away the headache of handling special characters in your own language, but pretty much (as I understand utf-8) all languages!

First, include the following meta-tag in the HTML head.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

You will also need to set UTF-8 at the top of all asp-files that are involved.

```
response.codepage = 65001
response.charset = "utf-8"
```

Do note though that characters posted to and from your asp-pages (via a form for example) will be interpreted as utf-8. Internally in the script engine strings is stored as unicode. 
Make sure that consistently save the data as unicode in the database.

**Read the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937509/internal-string-encoding) for more in-depth information**

Comment: I know that. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> is included on every page, but when i load data from DB it gets changed to utf-8 automaticaly and on page that data is corrupted. DB data type change is not an option cos our DB is too big, and used widely. This is unique problem cos of 2 different sources of data (.asp LIB and DB). I am thinking to get response from ajax then filter it (.filter()) and add charset=utf-8 to dropdown Label, and charset=windows-1252 on dropdown options data. Cant find how to filter both things at same time cos 1 part gets deleted

Comment: It's is an awful idea to store utf-8 inside a database. Any operation on that data from let's say SQL have to know it's utf-8. For such a simple operation as measuring a string length yo urun into big troubles. Store unicode inside your db.

Comment: @Paul I changed my answer based on your comment. Please verify that I got it right. If correct it would be nice if you removed the negative vote. Have a nice friday! :)

Comment: @David, that's better ;-) almost right now. the Post is not the-facto interpreted as utf-8 it depends on the codepage of the page you are posting to. But since you def. want to use the same setting everywhere in this example it shall be utf-8. Which happens also to be (the default) case if you are using for example jquery. Generally speaking utf-8 gives the poss. to use all languages, inside the page string however (vars) are 'converted' to unicode. So the asp pages should be saved as utf-8 (to give static string the poss. to be utf-8) but the strings you are handling are unicode neg.removed