# Processing non-English strings passed through QueryString

Tags: encoding, asp-classic, ascii, urlencode

I'm trying to process Hebrew string passed through QueryString with the classic ASP.

The URL I request to:
http://www.XXXX.com/myapp.asp?q=שלום

(שלום is "peace" in hebrew, a word consisting of 4 letters)

On the ASP side I run the following code:

```
mstr = Request.QueryString("q")
for i=1 to Len(mstr)
   Response.Write  Asc(Mid(mstr, i, 1)) & "<br/>"
next
```

This script generates the following output:
215
169
215
156
215
149
215
157

8 ASCII letters, which means two ASCII symbols (bytes) per letter.

I need to see the following output:
249
236
229
237

(The top part of the ASCII table)

What should I do to be able processing such strings correctly? (to see 4 letters as it sent in the original string).

Answer (score 0):

The html-page where the [http://www.XXXX.com/myapp.asp?q=שלום](http://www.XXXX.com/myapp.asp?q=%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D) link is, must be encoded as **utf-8**.
because the browser will encode the request (most likely) in the same encoding as the originating page.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

The querystring though should always be URL encoded. The browser does this automatically for standard links, but if you are constructing the URL through JavaScript you must take care of URL encoding yourself.

Secondly, you must set the server-side script (ASP) to work in utf-8. You can do this by having these lines at the top.

```
<%
    response.codepage = 65001
    response.charset = 'utf-8'
%>
```

**read more**:
[internal string encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937509/internal-string-encoding)